# Extracting the class labels and bounding boxes for objects, from a YOLO7 model after converting to an ONNX model

Tags: machine-learning, python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

At work, we use Unity, we have a project that needs object detection and classification. We decided to use this YOLO7 [model](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) (for non-technical reasons, It had to be this exact same model as the company does have pre-trained weights for this exact model). However, Unity only supports ONNX so I exported the model as an ONNX model, using the code provided in the repo:

```
python export.py --weights yolov7-tiny.pt --grid --end2end --simplify \
--topk-all 100 --iou-thres 0.65 --conf-thres 0.35 --img-size 640 640 --max-wh 640
```

however, I noticed if I import this in Unity, it gives warnings about **Resize** not being supported, and **end2end Flatten** not being supported. Both of which are documented [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@1.0/manual/SupportedOperators.html).

I removed --end2end from the export flags, which removed the warning, and for the Resize warning I followed the advice on a similar [issue](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/barracuda-release/issues/271)

> Opset 9 would mean Split will be version 2

so I switched this [line](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/export.py#L159) inside **export.py** to use version **9** instead of **12**

This removed all the warnings, however, the shape of the output of the ONNX model once imported into Unity is now as follows:
n:1 h:1 w:85 c:25200

I am not sure, how to extract the class label and the bounding box from this output shape. I was expecting a shape to include the following: *a number of detections per image*, *probability score for all or some of the labels*, and a *bounding box* for the objects. seeing as the shape is fixed, I believe my assumption is wrong.

After digging up the original repo, I believe what I am trying to do, is something similar to lines [here](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/detect.py#L100) but I honestly could not decipher what the code is doing there. furthermore, I am not sure it is correct to assume the extract from a PyTorch model is the same as from the ONNX model (because I am not sure if the exportation did change something).

Finally, I tried to look if someone has done similar work for the ONNX model and I found this [repo](https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/ONNX-YOLOv7-Object-Detection/blob/main/yolov7/YOLOv7.py) which links the same repo I am trying to use, and I believe this [function](https://github.com/ibaiGorordo/ONNX-YOLOv7-Object-Detection/blob/main/yolov7/YOLOv7.py#L71) is doing exactly what I want to do, but I could not understand what it is doing (I don't understand how it knows exactly where the number of detections is, and where the bounding boxes are and the class labels, etc.) furthermore, I am not sure if removing **end2end** and the changing the version from **12 to 9** has any effect on the output shape or it has to do with the internal layers.

To summarize my main questions are:

1- How to understand the output shape of the ONNX model?

2- How do I extract the class label, the probability, and the bounding box of the objects?

3- Does removing the end2end flag and the version number have hidden effects (as it may cause the model to produce incorrect results) or should I safely assume it has only to do with the accuracy of the model?

Comment: For the question number two, have you tried https://github.com/tsutof/tiny_yolov2_onnx_cam/blob/master/tiny_yolov2_onnx_cam.py#L248-L249 -> https://github.com/tsutof/tiny_yolov2_onnx_cam/blob/master/data_processing.py#L136?